# Why doesn't native Laravel 5.4 authentication send to password reset page?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I made a basic project in Laravel 5.4 using PhpStorm and executed `php artisan make:auth` and `php artisan migrate`. After running `php artisan serve`, I accessed the resulting site on http://localhost:8000 and tested the password recovery. Using Gmail for SMTP, the corresponding user received an e-mail with a link like this:

http://localhost/password/reset/d55b8591a690c96742e192d31ba6b1c7b06cb4b390fa08baaf02ce261618b884

It redirects me to a 404 Error page.

Looking at `php artisan route:list`, there is a route called `"password.reset"`, set on GET|HEAD with the following URI: `password/reset/{token}`. So it seams that should work, since there is a place for a token. The action is: `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm`

There's basically nothing on that controller, but it has `use ResetsPassword` from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth` inside the class. When I try to overwrite the function, I look at the original and it does redirect to reset password view.

But something is not working. I tried to add :8000 to the link, but it just redirects me to a blank page and I'm sure the server is still serving at that port. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `APP_URL=http://localhost` to `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000` in the `.env`

Answer (score 0):

Your route in the email must have the ":8000" that is the port of your application. Your browser if looking for the same route but in just in the localhost route without a port

Comment: Thank you for your response, I noted the :8000 after I posted the question, but when i copy the link and add the port, it just redirects me to a blank page, while the artisan is serving.